# Asp.Net MVC - Catch Configuration Error for better handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.NET MVC3 and would like to catch Configuration Error.
E.g. DLL Version mismatch in Web.Config

Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think so because these occur before your code even runs

Comment: This error occurs before running your code.